# Powershell Script to read text file on OneDrive

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I'm trying to read a text file saved/shared on OneDrive via PowerShell. I can't seem to find a way to read the contents of the text file. I can query via Invoke-WebRequest, but I can't get the actual content of the file even digging .CONTENT.

How should I get the actual content of the text inside?

Comment: Hello! Please add the command line you've tried to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download files from OneDrive by authenticating using Get-Credentials using power shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541426/how-to-download-files-from-onedrive-by-authenticating-using-get-credentials-usin)